# How do I query for a specific day such as yesterday in Core Data?

Tags: core-data

In plain SQL (in my case: sqlite), I would be able to query for a specific date in a DATE column as follows:

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE date(dateColumn) = '2015-01-01'
```

This works because the date() function cuts off the time part of the DATE value.

Can I do something similar with Predicates in Core Data? Or do I have to use something where I determine the start and end of that day and then look for dates between the two date values?

Comment: *"Or do I have to use something where I determine the start and end of that day and then look for dates between the two date values?"* – Yes. This might help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24186284/nspredicate-without-consider-time-component-

Comment: Well, I guess that answers my question. Thanks